# Simultaneous Database write when using data-toggle collapse for PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Previously I asked about an accordion div that wasn't closing properly. [solved]

The overall task being developed is based on the concept of school 'lesson pages' being read. We want to record that the student has actually opened (with timestamp) and closed (with timestamp) the page, and the differential on the timestamps will also show if there was ample time spent to have really read the lesson.

In the same snippet from before, I need to record when the user opens/closes the accordion panel and write those events to the database. The snippet to open the panel is:

```
<h3 class="panel-title"><strong><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse<?php echo $x; ?>"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down'></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $title; ?> </a></strong></h3>
```

...and the snippet to close the panel is:

```
<p><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" ><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up'></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Close</a></p>
```

I thought to use some kind of onClick to record these events, but can't figure how to tie it together. The site is primarily PHP w/ HTML. Any suggestion would be appreciated.... Thanks.

Comment: You could use an onclick event to send an Ajax request to the server using jQuery. Then use whatever information you have about the student, (A session maybe?) to store the timestamp of the request in the database.  This comment is just to point you in a direction, because it would be flawed to use it as it is. A student could just send the requests whenever they want for exemple, I would probably use a token to work around this.

Comment: You could use Javascript to record the time the page is loaded, and also when the close button is clicked, then send both times and the interval via AJAX to the server. Or, instead of using AJAX, submit the page to a PHP script that records the event, and sets the navigation to the next page (maybe passed as a parameter). There may be times when a student is skipping past pages they have seen to get to one they haven't finished, so you may need some logic to ignore short "views" of pages,

Comment: Thanks folks-- each suggestion points to a valid possibility. My own ability with Ajax or jQuery is minimal however...  I can generally follow a simulation example, but not write it from scratch on my own. Since I do PHP mostly, I couldn't see a way to incorporate the DB write. The actual lesson pages are populated into the accordion panels with a 'while-loop' in PHP and a page counter to determine how many panels to build. So, each panel has it's own open/close link-- that's why I was looking for a way to attach this DB write to the link.

Comment: And the intent is to count the final open/closes with mysql to avoid skips, and also the duration spent on each panel/page. This is a piece by piece build. Thanks for the nibbles.